# XML Retrieving 2 XElements from different trees

Tags: c#, xml, linq

A sample of my XML file is as follows:-

```
<table>  
  <columns>
    <column>
      <area>
        <identifier>E31000040</identifier>
        <label>Gtr Manchester Fire</label>
        <altLabel>Gtr Manchester Fire</altLabel>
        <isSummary>false</isSummary>
      </area>
      <metricType>
        <identifier>948</identifier>
        <label>Accidental dwelling fires</label>
        <altLabel>Accidental dwelling fires</altLabel>
        <isSummary>false</isSummary>
      </metricType>
      <period>
        <identifier>fq_Q1_2007_08</identifier>
        <label>2007/08 Q1</label>
        <altLabel>2007/08 Q1</altLabel>
        <isSummary>false</isSummary>
      </period>
      <valueType>
        <identifier>raw</identifier>
        <label>Raw value</label>
        <isSummary>false</isSummary>
      </valueType>
    </column>
    <column>
      <area>
        <identifier>E31000040</identifier>
        <label>Gtr Manchester Fire</label>
        <altLabel>Gtr Manchester Fire</altLabel>
        <isSummary>false</isSummary>
      </area>
      <metricType>
        <identifier>948</identifier>
        <label>Accidental dwelling fires</label>
        <altLabel>Accidental dwelling fires</altLabel>
        <isSummary>false</isSummary>
      </metricType>
      <period>
        <identifier>fq_Q2_2007_08</identifier>
        <label>2007/08 Q2</label>
        <altLabel>2007/08 Q2</altLabel>
        <isSummary>false</isSummary>
      </period>
      <valueType>
        <identifier>raw</identifier>
        <label>Raw value</label>
        <isSummary>false</isSummary>
      </valueType>
    </column>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <values>
        <value>
          <source>732.0</source>
          <value>732.0</value>
          <formatted>732</formatted>
          <format>#,##0</format>
          <publicationStatus>Published</publicationStatus>
        </value>
        <value>
          <source>659.0</source>
          <value>659.0</value>
          <formatted>659</formatted>
          <format>#,##0</format>
          <publicationStatus>Published</publicationStatus>
        </value>
      </values>
    </row>
  </rows>
</table>
```

Firstly, I want to add to a grid, and eventually save to a sql database, each of the column period/Labels, along side the corresponding value.
I have tried various variations of the following code, all which don't match the period to the value.

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xml);

List<Results> period = new List<Results>();

var columnnodes = xd.Element("table")
                    .Elements("columns")
                    .Elements("column")
                    .Elements("period");

var rownodes = xd.Element("table")
                 .Elements("rows")
                 .Elements("row")
                 .Elements("values")
                 .Elements("value");

foreach (XElement ele in columnnodes)
{
    Results newResult = new Results();
    newResult.period = (string)ele.Element("label");

    /*newResult.value = (int)xd.Element("table")
                             .Elements("rows")
                             .Elements("row")
                             .Elements("values")
                             .Elements("value")
                             .Elements("Formatted");

    period.Add(newResult);*/

    foreach (XElement ele2 in rownodes)
    {
        newResult.value = (int)ele2.Element("formatted");
    }

    period.Add(newResult);
}

gridResults.DataSource = period;
gridResults.DataBind();
```

Any clues on how to get them to align to a datagrid similar to:-

Period      Value

2007/08 Q1  732

2007/08 Q2  659

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set, produced from the sample xml of the OP, that you want to bind to the grid?

Comment: Added an example of the output/table, apologies for it being in a list format!

Comment: @Porkster - Did you get a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply extract periods and values in two separate lists:

```
var periods = from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("period")
              select p.Element("label").Value;

var values = from v in xmlDoc.Descendants("formatted")
             select v.Value;
```

and then just `.Zip` them together:

```
var results = periods.Zip(values, (p, v) => new { Period = p, Value = v });
```

to produce the required result set:

```
[0] = { Period = "2007/08 Q1", Value = "732" }
[1] = { Period = "2007/08 Q2", Value = "659" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problem with your XML file, first `<columns>` tag is not closed that must be after two `column` elements, the second and important one is within your `value` tree you again have a `value` element (which you want to fetch), this will definitely create problems because if you will look for descendants of `value`, then this item will be considered as well which will result in unexpected result.

So, I have replace your inner element with column name `amount`, you can give it any meaningful name and change the query accordingly:-

```
var period = xdoc.Descendants("period")
           .Select((x,index) => new
           {
              Period = (string)x.Element("label"),
              Value = x.Document.Root.Descendants("value")
                       .Where((v,i) => i == index)
                       .Select(z => (string)z.Element("amount")).FirstOrDefault()
           });
```

As you can see I am fetching the **Period** & **Value** present at same index in `columns` & `rows` tree respectively.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I Accidentally deleted the end </columns> while shortening the example. I was aware there were 2 nested 'value', however wasnt sure how to change one of them so thanks for that. As the data is from an external source, I have no input into the creation of that.